# [Jquery]: "Enter" key as invaild symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

So what I've got is a little validator which shows label with error if any of restricted symbols were entered in input, using this checker:

```
var ValidPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-Я\-.": ]*$/;
```

Problem is, "Enter" key counts as symbol which out of this checker. 
Also, I don't even know how this construction properly called `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-Я\-.": ]*$/"`, just keep guessing how it must work, maybe someone could say me what is the right definition of this, so I could read about it?

Anyway, if you still want to help with "Enter" issue, here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zjNj6/2/ (ValidPattern is on line 23)

Comment: I don't understand the question but **[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)** might be the answer (or part of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

You seem to want the ability to enter spaces (including new lines). Change your regex to

```
var ValidPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-Я\-.":\s]*$/;
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped, I will accept your answer after timer.